# Bulk print in javascript/php?

Tags: javascript, php, printing

Is there any way to implement bulk/mass print in javascript/php? I searched on web and most of the answers found are for `.net` and `java`. I need to queue around 600 documents at a time. I found [PECL printer library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.printer.php) but the doc says it is `only available under Windows 9.x, ME, NT4 and 2000`. Does `PECL library` work under linux server? is it good to go with PECL library or there are any other alternatives?

Comment: The extension you're looking at is simply called "printer". PECL is the name of the site that you would be able to obtain it from… **if** a stable version of the extension had ever been released. None ever has, and the library hasn't been under active development in over five years.

Comment: Where are you printing?  The server?  The client?  What are you printing?

Comment: @Brad I need to print several documents in the client side. These documents are dynamically created and will be in different formats. I need to queue all documents at once and the client should also be able to control printer attributes like printer, number of pages etc.

Answer (score 2):

Controlling the Printer in Windows is not big task as we have many win32api available or entry points can be created to do printing dynamically. As PHP is the server side and JavaScript is Client side scripting language.

Bulk Printing/Printing on Client Side without permission/notification is not possible according to me. Thus, user must authorize the printing job.

Developers have less experience for Printing under Linux. Even me don't know much but I know a way to do it. I have never tried or done it yet. Under PHP doesn't have any inbuilt function of printing/controlling things. There is no extension as such available under PHP to do so also. But under Linux there is command know as LPR (***Line printer daemon protocol***) which can be used under PHP to do printing, if shell_exec is authorized under PHP to execute shell commands. Command follows a:

```
shell_exec("lpr -P 'printer' -r 'filename.txt');
```

You have to go through [RFC Protocol](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1179.html) for LPR. You have to create the abstraction layer for Daemon for controlling and sending Printing Commands. A Good example for creating daemon is available [here](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2540-PHP-Abstraction-for-printing-documents.html).

After going through these things, you would be able to Print documents under Linux through PHP.

## Additional Question

Want to do Client Side Printing through Website/localhost

### Small Answer

No, you can't control the Client Printer Directly without permission of user and that too depends on every session. So, if you want to get the access is another session you have to get the permission of user again.

### Long Answer

Yes, it can be controlled with many tweaks and under certain conditions. As most of the users use windows as providing answer accordingly. But to understand the working of that you have to understand the Print Dialog internals.

Print Dialog is divided into two parts. One is Windows API and other is Printer Drivers. Windows API is the set of common code that is held by various DLL (Dynamic Link Library) that are the part Windows OS. Windows API provide a common interference allowing all Program can use that allowing all programs access to the same set of printer drivers rather than printer manufacturers having to create driver software.

Printer Drivers are created in different languages and they control the different parts of the hardware to send the instructions to printer. The main Printer Driver that control the flow are PCL5 and PostScript etc., Printer Driver changes the custom markup language that the specific printer understands.

So, basically we need the direct access to DLL and through Modern Browsers (Chrome, Firefox etc.) it is not possible but One Browser can Provide the access i.e. Internet Explore which is Part of Windows OS itself.

So, the **First Condition is the User must use Internet Explorer** and access through other is not known to me. Next thing to get the direct access to the API that can be done through ActiveX Control.  In principle it is not dependent on Microsoft Windows, but in practice, most ActiveX controls require either Microsoft Windows or a Windows emulator. Most also require the **client to be running on Intel x86 hardware, because they contain compiled code**.

So, the ActiveX Controls are accessed through user prompt only. Thus, use have to manually change the control or again user has to provide the access to the web page. If the settings are changed then there is great danger to the computer as it provide access to computer hardware and other components. The computer can be hacked easily. Thus, you have to use it under great cautions. Thus, **Third condition is to have a direct access to ActiveX Control**.

I have used [ScriptX](http://scriptx.meadroid.com/), free version lets you set some basic parameters, see the example below:

```
<!-- MeadCo ScriptX -->
<object id=factory style="display:none"
  classid="clsid:1663ed61-23eb-11d2-b92f-008048fdd814"
  codebase="http://[your path here]/smsx.cab#Version=7.0.0.8 ">
</object>


<script>
  function printWindow() {
    factory.printing.header = "This is MeadCo";
    factory.printing.footer = "Printing by ScriptX";
    factory.printing.portrait = false;
    factory.printing.leftMargin = 1.0;
    factory.printing.topMargin = 1.0;
    factory.printing.rightMargin = 1.0;
    factory.printing.bottomMargin = 1.0;
    factory.printing.Print(false);
  }
</script>
```

I have provided the way to do it and rest you have to do according to your requirements. Once again I would tell you that kindly not change the settings of ActiveX to enable which caused great threat to user. Machine can be easily hacked and great threat to information available in computer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Vineet1982, +1. I need to perform client side printing. Will i be able to do that? and can i control printer properties?

Comment: @Console provided you reply to query

Comment: Thank you for the really good explanation but i am really looking answers for the Linux server. I will provide you the bounty as it helped me and will definitely help others in future.

Comment: @Console did u want to say bulk printing client side using linux not windows

Answer (score 1):

The `PECL printer library` is for server-side printing. You have to have the printer connected to the server the script is running on.

If your clients need to do the printing, you cannot use it. You cannot do the "printer queueing" with JS alone. If you are restricted to using the browser only, best way to go about this would be loading out all the pages you want to print in one HTML page with proper CSS page breaks. But beware, there might be browser performance issues depending on the size of that one page.

Another thing you could do is convert that HTML internally to a PDF and then allow clients to print it. This doesn't allow queueing, but serves the purpose.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out @KPL, +1. But will the solution be feasible if the client has to print about 600 documents at a time?

Comment: Yes, you can use this for printing as many pages as possible. My preferred method would be converting the HTML to PDF and then allowing the clients to print that. You can use something like wkhtmltopdf (http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/‎) to do the conversion.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use css [page-break-before](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebb.asp) to tell the browser that the content should be in a new page and clone the element as many time as you want

for example

```css
.page
{
    page-break-before: always;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  something to be printed in a whole page
</div>

<div class="page">
  something to be printed in a whole page
</div>

<div class="page">
  something to be printed in a whole page
</div>
```